# DB2 Foreign Keys Based on Bitwise Operations

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Some time ago,  I created a custom CMS for the company I currently work for.  Our company has multiple divisions and each had to be accounted for.  Those working with division A would only be able to access documents that were deemed appropriate for them.  The same goes for division B.  Some documents could be used in both divisions.  I wanted to avoid mostly duplicate records, though, so that instead of having a record for a specific document in division A and basically an identical record for division B, I used the bit-wise AND operation to handle the request.

The relevant table information is as follows:

```
DOCUMENT Table
ID       NAME             DIVISIONS
-----------------------------------
1        Document 1       3
2        Document 2       2
3        Document 3       1

DIVISIONS Table
ID       DIVISION
-------------------
1        DIVISION A
2        DIVISION B
```

The following query:

```
SELECT A.NAME, B.DIVISION 
FROM DOCUMENT AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIVISIONS AS B ON LAND(A.DIVISIONS,B.ID)=B.ID 
WHERE B.DIVISION='DIVISION A'
```

would produce the Result Set:

```
NAME         DIVISION
------------------------
Document 1   DIVISION A
Document 3   DIVISION A
```

and likewise the following Result Set when B.DIVISION='DIVISION B'

```
NAME         DIVISION
------------------------
Document 1   DIVISION B
Document 2   DIVISION B
```

For my uses, this works just fine with no noticeable slowdowns.  But in a larger environment, the lack of a keyed relationship could hurt the speed of these transactions.  Also, it becomes more difficult to keep referential integrity in the off chance we drop a division.

Is there any way to have a Foreign Key that is actually a function of two values?  While this particular issue pertains to my company's iSeries (AS400) and DB2 for the iSeries, it is really a question that could be answered for any DBMS.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you get rid of bitmaps in favor of association tables?

Comment: mu...are you suggesting having a table simply with the document's id and a site id?  I suppose I could, but the bitmaps were used to avoid having another table

Comment: That's the standard way to do it in SQL. The "multiple fields in one column" approach (also seen as CSVs inside a column) start out seeming like a quick way to make things go but it always falls apart into a big pile of nastiness. You really shouldn't be afraid of adding more tables in a relational system, RDBMSs are pretty good at working with and joining tables, that's what they do.

Answer (score 5):

As **Mu** commented - an association table is the proper design.

```
DOCUMENT_DIVISIONS Table
ID    DOCUMENT_ID    DIVISION_ID
--------------------------------
1     1              1
2     1              2
3     2              2
4     3              1
```

Then it's simply a matter of joining the document and division through the association:

```
SELECT A.NAME, C.DIVISION 
FROM DOCUMENT AS A
JOIN DOCUMENT_DIVISIONS AS B ON A.ID = B.DOCUMENT_ID
JOIN DIVISIONS AS C ON C.ID = B.DIVISION_ID
WHERE C.DIVISION = 'DIVISION A'
```

Comment: And then FKs are nice and easy to set up to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can have more than one column in a foreign key constraint the diagram below shows more than one column name.

[Db2 Basics Constraints](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0401melnyk/)

[image: constraint diagram]

I always use the constraint type of restrict on the AS400 this way the data doesn't change by itself or magically cascade delete.  you just get an error same as if you inserted a duplicate record in a unique file.  You can easily remember this on the as400 because of "R"PG restrict.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Can you show the code that would do what the OP asked?